# How to add a progress bar to a DataGridView while loading the data 1 to 100% when complete loading

Tags: c#, sql-server, c#-4.0

I need help with my application, everything in my application works, but I want to add one last detail that will help the user when using the application.

I have a combobox that has three selections the user will use, each selection has different warehouse database environment. so if they select in the combobox warehouse1 then will load database 1 table data to the datagridview but when they select the application is loading to show the data, so when is doing that depending how much data is sometimes takes to 5 to 15 seconds to load or more I want to add a progress bar so lets the user know to wait until the progress reaches the 100%.

So I need help on that how to make the progress bar to work while the datagridview is loading the data. if you need more information please let me know.

after the changes please check, but i am getting an error
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

```
        //the issue I am having is the progress bar to while the datagridview is loading, the datagridview will load after the user selects the combobox selection
        //the combobox event handler will fill the datagridview and the forms loads and I want while loading the progress bar to show the percentage that is loading 1 to 100%
```

updated code:
            //global variables
        //datagridview, bindingsource, data_apapter global objects variables
        private DataGridView dataGridView = new DataGridView();
        private BindingSource bindingSource = new BindingSource();
        private SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();

```
    //class objects
    Databases lemars = new Databases();
    Databases schuyler = new Databases();
    Databases detroitlakeskc = new Databases();
    /*
     *   The GetLeMarsConnectionDatabaseConnection method starts the database string connection for warehouse LeMars21St 
    */
    private void GetLeMarsConnectionDatabaseConnection(string selectCommand, Databases database)
    {

        try
        {

            //Create the connection string, data adapter and data table.
            String connectionString = database.LeMarsConnectionString;


            // Specify a connection string. Replace the given value with a 
            // valid connection string for a Northwind SQL Server sample
            // database accessible to your system.
            // Create a new data adapter based on the specified query.
            dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(selectCommand, connectionString);

            // Create a command builder to generate SQL update, insert, and
            // delete commands based on selectCommand. These are used to
            // update the database.
            SqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);

            // Populate a new data table and bind it to the BindingSource.
            System.Data.DataTable table = new System.Data.DataTable();
            table.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
            dataAdapter.Fill(table);
            bindingSource.DataSource = table;

            // Resize the DataGridView columns to fit the newly loaded content.
            dataGridView_ShowAllData.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCellsExceptHeader);

        }
        //catch the error if cannot get a database connection
        catch (SqlException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("FootPrint-LEMARS Database couldn't received a connection ***ERROR***");
        }

    }


    private void cmb_DatabaseSelection_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //Boolean selection statements to Fill the DataGridView based on the user selecction
        if (cmb_DatabaseSelection.SelectedItem == "LeMars21St")
        {
            dataGridView_ShowAllData.DataSource = bindingSource;

            //query with 11 columns
            GetLeMarsConnectionDatabaseConnection("Select * from dbo.AllInvoicesInReadyStatus", lemars);


        }

        private void bgnWorker_LoadingForm_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: query your database
        // for easier reading I assume that your query-result has only one column
        //string query = @"Select * from dbo.AllInvoicesInReadyStatus";
        //** did you strip your sql-execution-code? have a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx


        var queryResult = new List<object>();
        bgnWorker_LoadingForm.ReportProgress(10);

        var table = new System.Data.DataTable();
        // TODO: create matching columns for your query-result in the datatable
        // https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.data.datatable.newrow(v=vs.110).aspx
        // Create new DataTable and DataSource objects. 

        // Declare DataColumn and DataRow variables.
        DataColumn column;
        DataRow row;
        DataView view;

        // Create new DataColumn, set DataType, ColumnName, and add to DataTable.    
        column = new DataColumn();
        column.DataType = typeof(string);
        column.ColumnName = "invoice";
        table.Columns.Add(column);

        // Create second column. 
        column = new DataColumn();
        column.DataType = typeof(string);
        column.ColumnName = "shipment";
        table.Columns.Add(column);

        // Create third column. 
        column = new DataColumn();
        column.DataType = typeof(string);
        column.ColumnName = "Project";
        table.Columns.Add(column);

        // Create fourth column. 
        column = new DataColumn();
        column.DataType = typeof(DateTime);
        column.ColumnName = "invoiceDateTB";
        table.Columns.Add(column);

        // Create fifth column. 
        column = new DataColumn();
        column.DataType = typeof(DateTime);
        column.ColumnName = "CreatedDate";
        table.Columns.Add(column);

        // Create sixth column. 
        column = new DataColumn();
        column.DataType = typeof(string);
        column.ColumnName = "typeName";
        table.Columns.Add(column);

        // Create seventh column. 
        column = new DataColumn();
        column.DataType = typeof(string);
        column.ColumnName = "statusName";
        table.Columns.Add(column);

        // Create eighth column. 
        column = new DataColumn();
        column.DataType = typeof(decimal);
        column.ColumnName = "total";
        table.Columns.Add(column);

        // Create ninth column. 
        column = new DataColumn();
        column.DataType = typeof(string);
        column.ColumnName = "import_status";
        table.Columns.Add(column);

        // Create tenth column. 
        column = new DataColumn();
        column.DataType = typeof(DateTime); 
        column.ColumnName = "Time_Completed";
        table.Columns.Add(column);

        // Create eleventh column. 
        column = new DataColumn();
        column.DataType = typeof(string);
        column.ColumnName = "ERROR_DESCRIPTION";
        table.Columns.Add(column);



        for (var i = 0; i < queryResult.Count; i++)
        {
            var progress = 10 + (int)((float)i / queryResult.Count) * 90;
            bgnWorker_LoadingForm.ReportProgress(progress);
            //** dont know whats going on here
            //** but normally you should iterate your data-reader here and transfer the data of your query result to the created row... like this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/haa3afyz(v=vs.110).aspx
            row = table.NewRow();
            row["invoice"].ToString();
            row["shipment"].ToString();
            row["Project"].ToString();
            row["invoiceDateTB"] = typeof(DateTime);
            row["CreatedDate"] = typeof(DateTime);
            row["typeName"].ToString();
            row["statusName"].ToString();
            row["total"] = typeof(decimal);
            row["import_status"].ToString();
            row["Time_Completed"] = typeof(DateTime);
            row["ERROR_DESCRIPTION"].ToString();

            table.Rows.Add(row);

            // TODO: add the row data to the table
            // same link as before: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.data.datatable.newrow(v=vs.110).aspx
        }

        //**begin: move this stuff to worker completed
        // Create a DataView using the DataTable. . 
        view = new DataView(table);
        //**end

        // Set a DataGrid control's DataSource to the DataView.
        dataGridView_ShowAllData.DataSource = view;

        e.Result = table;
    }

    private void bgnWorker_LoadingForm_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Data.DataTable table = (System.Data.DataTable)e.Result;
        // TODO: Check for errors
        // TODO: Assign the table to your grid
        // TODO: unlock your ui, hide progress dialog
    }

    private void bgnWorker_LoadingForm_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: update your progress dialog/progressbar, f.e.
        prgBar_DataGridViewLoading.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (bgnWorker_LoadingForm.IsBusy) return;
        bgnWorker_LoadingForm.RunWorkerAsync();
        // TODO: lock your ui, show progress dialog or progressbar...
    }
```

Comment: You can't do that with a fill method since you don't have any control over the  loop.  You would have to adjust your query and code to get a record count and then loop through the records to fill your table using a separate thread.  Or just set the progress bar to a marque style.

Comment: I see, can you show example to have control when filling the datadridview or the progress bar  marque style

Comment: `progressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee;`

Comment: can you show a full code how would it and work? I haven't done much with progress bar or the control of the datagridview

Comment: You can't do this with your code at all. You would have to write a different piece of sql to get your data in chunks and increment the progress bar after you execute each query. It would add tons of complexity and make the overall process slower.

Comment: I see your point, so now another question, can we add the progress bar to load while the form is being loading, because while the user select the combobox the form freezes because is loading the datagridview, so while the form is loading can we add the progress bar until the forms loading because of the datagridview

Comment: See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-make-thread-safe-calls-to-windows-forms-controls).

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it the manual way with a `BackgroundWorker` (`WorkerReportsProgress = true`) if you want 'real'-progress...

quick-and-dirty-description:

1) In the `BackgroundWorker.DoWork` function query your table (f.e. 10%), create the matching DataTable locally, iterate the result and add it to a your local DataTable (10-100%).

2) Use `ReportProgress` to send the current progress state from inside `BackgroundWorker.DoWork` to your ui.

3) In `BackgroundWorker.ProgressChanged` you can safely update your ui/progressbar.

4) Then return (assign the value to the `DoWorkEventArgs.Result`) the local DataTable as a result of `BackgroundWorker.DoWork`...

5) and retrieve the result in `BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted` by accessing `RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs.Result` and assign the DataTable to your DataGrid

quick-and-dirty-example...

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: query your database
        // for easier reading I assume that your query-result has only one column
        var queryResult = new List<object>();
        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(10);

        var table = new DataTable();
        // TODO: create matching columns for your query-result in the datatable
        // https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.data.datatable.newrow(v=vs.110).aspx

        for (var i = 0; i < queryResult.Count; i++)
        {
            var progress = 10 + (int)((float)i / queryResult.Count) * 90;
            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(progress);

            // TODO: add the row data to the table
            // same link as before: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.data.datatable.newrow(v=vs.110).aspx
        }

        e.Result = table;
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable table = (DataTable)e.Result;
        // TODO: Check for errors
        // TODO: Assign the table to your grid
        // TODO: unlock your ui, hide progress dialog
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: update your progress dialog/progressbar, f.e.
        progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (backgroundWorker1.IsBusy) return;
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        // TODO: lock your ui, show progress dialog or progressbar...
    }
}
```

***not tested, since i have a) no test-data and b) building up a full example is very time-consuming. I also might have forget something, but this could be one way to go...***

Comment: I will check into this and if I have extra questions I will let you know, but if not asking to much can you a sample code of your statements

Comment: sorry i didnt see your code example I will make a test and let you know the results

Comment: the Select * from dbo.AllInvoicesInReadyStatus query will display 11 columns of data

Comment: I made changes please check my issue and if I am missing something please check above

Comment: @AndresBryan29 First: Your code is getting really large here - try to keep it small! About the code... 1) The **sql-query-execution** is still missing in the `DoWork` function. You're still assigning the created  `DataTable` in the `DoWork` function - assign the `DataTable` in the `RunWorkerCompleted` function. In the loop inside of `DoWork` you're calling `ToString` without doing anything with the created string... why?

Answer (score 0):

Dont forget to read Alexander Petrov's link... I post a second answer instead of commenting your post to have syntax highlighting... Please remeber that i can't test your code, but i have added some comments, prefixed with a **

```
private void bgnWorker_LoadingForm_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: query your database
        // for easier reading I assume that your query-result has only one column
        //string query = @"Select * from dbo.AllInvoicesInReadyStatus";
        //** did you strip your sql-execution-code? have a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx

        var queryResult = new List<object>();
        //queryResult.Add(query);
        bgnWorker_LoadingForm.ReportProgress(10);

        var table = new System.Data.DataTable();
        // TODO: create matching columns for your query-result in the datatable
        // https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.data.datatable.newrow(v=vs.110).aspx
        // Create new DataTable and DataSource objects. 

        // Declare DataColumn and DataRow variables.
        DataColumn column;
        DataRow row;
        DataView view;

        // Create new DataColumn, set DataType, ColumnName, and add to DataTable.    
        column = new DataColumn();
        //** you could write just typeof(string) here...
        column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
        column.ColumnName = "invoice";
        table.Columns.Add(column);

        // Create second column. 
        column = new DataColumn();
        column.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");
        column.ColumnName = "shipment";
        table.Columns.Add(column);

        // Create second column. 
        column = new DataColumn();
        column.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");
        column.ColumnName = "Project";
        table.Columns.Add(column);

        // Create second column. 
        column = new DataColumn();
        column.DataType = Type.GetType("System.DateTime");
        column.ColumnName = "invoiceDateTB";
        table.Columns.Add(column);

        // Create second column. 
        column = new DataColumn();
        column.DataType = Type.GetType("System.DateTime");
        column.ColumnName = "CreatedDate";
        table.Columns.Add(column);

        // Create second column. 
        column = new DataColumn();
        column.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");
        column.ColumnName = "typeName";
        table.Columns.Add(column);

        // Create second column. 
        column = new DataColumn();
        column.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");
        column.ColumnName = "statusName";
        table.Columns.Add(column);

        // Create second column. 
        column = new DataColumn();
        column.DataType = Type.GetType("System.Int32");
        column.ColumnName = "total";
        table.Columns.Add(column);

        // Create second column. 
        column = new DataColumn();
        column.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");
        column.ColumnName = "import_status";
        table.Columns.Add(column);

        // Create second column. 
        column = new DataColumn();
        column.DataType = Type.GetType("System.DateTime");
        column.ColumnName = "Time_Completed";
        table.Columns.Add(column);

        // Create second column. 
        column = new DataColumn();
        column.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");
        column.ColumnName = "ERROR_DESCRIPTION";
        table.Columns.Add(column);



        for (var i = 0; i < queryResult.Count; i++)
        {
            var progress = 10 + (int)((float)i / queryResult.Count) * 90;
            bgnWorker_LoadingForm.ReportProgress(progress);

            row = table.NewRow();
        //** dont know whats going on here
        //** but normally you should iterate your data-reader here and transfer the data of your query result to the created row... like this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/haa3afyz(v=vs.110).aspx
            row["invoice"] = i;
            row["shipment"] = "shipment" + i.ToString();
            row["Project"] = "Project" + i.ToString();
            row["invoiceDateTB"].ToString();
            row["CreatedDate"].ToString(); ;
            row["typeName"] = "typeName" + i.ToString();
            row["statusName"] = "statusName" + i.ToString();
            row["total"].ToString();
            row["import_status"] = "import_status" + i.ToString();
            row["Time_Completed"].ToString(); ;
            row["ERROR_DESCRIPTION"] = "ERROR_DESCRIPTION" + i.ToString();

            table.Rows.Add(row);

            // TODO: add the row data to the table
            // same link as before: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.data.datatable.newrow(v=vs.110).aspx
        }

        //**begin: move this stuff to worker completed
        // Create a DataView using the DataTable. 
        view = new DataView(table);

        // Set a DataGrid control's DataSource to the DataView.
        dataGridView_ShowAllData.DataSource = view;
        //**end

        e.Result = table;
    }
```

Comment: Sounds I will review this and test it and let know the results thanks.

Comment: tried I am still getting the following error  InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'dataGridView_ShowAllData' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

Comment: @AndresBryan29 Please update your first post with your current code so we can see whats happening... Please include all three BackgroundWorker functions: DoWork, ProgressChanged and RunWorkerCompleted

Comment: I will add the current code so you can see the issue I am having

Comment: I added the update code please review it and let me know.